# How can fix System.StackOverflow Exception?

Tags: c#, class, exception

I used 2 classes, and I need send/receive methods and variables. But when I make an instance of this class it gives me a `System.StackOverflowException`.

How can fix this problem?

This is my code:

```
class Setup1
{
   Setup2 set2 = new Setup();

   int a = 5;

   public int myMethod();
   {
      set2.b =  a + 10;
      return set2.b;
   }
}

class Setup2
{
    Setup1 set1 = new Setup();
    public int b = 0;
    void  Show()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(set1.myMethod());
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you use the debugger? Set Breakpoints? single step through your code? Stack Overflow Eception usually means a recursive call without end condition.

Comment: You have some typos in your code (or it is not complete) It will not compile. `Setup` => `Setup2` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an infinite recursion.

In the constructor of `Setup2()` you call the constructor of `Setup1()`. There you call the constructor of `Setup2()`and so on, infinitely. Your memory runs out, and your stack overflows.

Comment: what i should to do?because I need make class object for every classes, due to i need use methods and variable from every classes

Comment: Rethink your overall design. Do not call one constructor inside another constructor for no good reason. You could have a central place where you construct all the classes you need.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have cyclic constructor calling that leads to stack-overflow exception.